# Attribute error: 'bytes' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to save data received from API in file in json format.

```
response = requests.get(url_league,   headers= header)
type(response)
#output requests.models.Response
with open("json.txt", "w+") as f:
    data = json.dump(response, f)
```

When i trying to save response object to file i got the following error

```
Object of type Response is not JSON serializable
```

I read that json module have problems with encoding complex objects and for this purposes in json have default function to encode complex objects. I tried the following code

```
json_data = json.dump(response.__dict__, f, default = lambda o: o.__dict__, indent=4)
```

And got the following error

```
bytes' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

What this error mean and how to solve it?

Comment: have you tried using `response.json()`?

Comment: Wonderfull) i tried and get what i want. Thank you man

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting means that response is of type "bytes", and not text/JSON. You need to decode your response first (you need urllib or urllib2).

```
import json
import urllib.request

response=urllib.request.urlopen(url_league).read()
string = response.decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)

with open("json.txt", "w+") as f:
    data = json.dump(json_obj, f)
```

To use headers you can just use

```
req = Request(url)
req.add_header('apikey', 'xxx')
```